# Remove SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a production server with following server configuration.

- IBM XSERIES 346
- Intel Xeon 3.23 GHz
- RAM 4GB

Now, I have uninstalled Microsoft SQL Server 2005 recently and tried to reinstall SQL Server 2005 again. But it is saying that existing components are already installed and can not reinstall again.

Note that I found nothing in Uninstall Programs and Features list. I have cleaned the registry, and other caches. But the problem is still there.

Can you please help me with solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would first start by reviewing the setup logs, [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144287(v=sql.90).aspx).  The log should show more information in regards to what it does not like.  SQL does install components that are listed in "Uninstall Programs" with names other than "SQL", in other words hidden in plain sight.